# Getting an ID as well as Coordinates from Leaflet marker on dragend

Tags: leaflet

I am looping through an array and loading markers on a map. I would like to update the coordinates of the array element if the marker is moved.

My code so far is like this:

```js
var m;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var plateNo = data[i].PLATE_NUMBER;
  var trackingNo = data[i].TRACKING_NUMBER;
  var inventoryId = data[i].INVENTORY_ID;
  if (data[i].INVENTORY_STATUS !== 'Complete') {
    var icon = epsMarker.incompleteIcon;
    var popup = '<h5>EPS</h5>' + 'Plate:' + plateNo + '<br/>' + '</p>';

    m = L.marker([data[i].REF_LATITUDE, data[i].REF_LONGITUDE], {
        icon: icon,
        draggable: 'true'
      })
      .bindPopup(popup);

    m.on('dragend', function (event) {
      var marker = event.target;
      var position = marker.getLatLng();
      console.log(position);
      //Call Database and Update Position by INVENTORY_ID 
    });
  }
}
```

I can get the Lat and Long but I would also like to get the INVENTORY_ID parameter. The idea is to look up the data on the Database by INVENTORY_ID  and then update the lat and long.

I appreciate any help or pointers on this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the ID in your marker as an option or member property so you can later retrieve it:

```
// Store as option
var marker = L.marker([0,0], {id: INVENTORY_ID}).addTo(map);
console.log(marker.options.id);

// Store as member property
var marker = L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map);
marker.id = INVENTORY_ID;
console.log(marker.id);
```

Comment: Thanks, either of those would work. My final code is like this, in case anyone else would like to find an attribute on dragend event

 m = L.marker([data[i].REF_LATITUDE, data[i].REF_LONGITUDE], { id: data[i].INVENTORY_ID, icon: icon, draggable: 'true' })
                        .bindPopup(popup);

                    m.on('dragend', function (event) {
                      var marker = event.target;
                       var position = marker.getLatLng();
                        console.log(marker.options.id);
                    });